# Azure B2C custom Sign In journey - Capture email first

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have a custom user journey with following requirements

1. capture user email
2. check idp associated with that email in b2c
3. relay to the idp login page

I can capture the email address but it only works for local accounts not for Azure AD or social logins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for a HRD (Home Realm Discovery) solution. Use this sample as a starting point to build out your scenario.

[A B2C IEF Custom Policy - A Sign In policy with Home Realm Discovery and a Default Identity Provider](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/default-home-realm-discovery)

> For scenarios where you need to implement a sign in journey, where the
> user is automatically directed to their federated identity provider
> based off of their email domain. And for users who arrive with an
> unknown domain, they are redirected to a default identity provider.
>
> In this example, users who enter an email with the suffix contoso.com,
> they will be redirected directly to their federated identity provider
> to sign in. In this case that is Azure AD (SAML2).
>
> Users who enter an email with the suffix facebook.com, they will be
> redirected directly to their federated identity provider to sign in.
> In this case that is Facebook (OAuth).
>
> Where a user comes from an unknown email suffix, they will be
> redirected directly to a default identity provider, in this case that
> is Azure AD (OpenId).